# Off-resonant Rabi oscillations

Tags: quantum-spin, quantum-optics, rabi-model

If I have a laser field that causes Rabi oscillation of a two-level system, I can use the Hamiltonian

$H=-\frac{\Delta}{2}\sigma_z+\frac{\Omega}{2}\sigma_x$

where $\Omega$ is the Rabi frequency of the pulse, $\Delta$ is the detuning of the two-level system from the pulse resonance and $\sigma_i$ are the Pauli matrices to describe the system. I can then act the time evolution operator $U=e^{-iHt}$ onto an initial state of the system, taken to be the ground state $|\psi>=|0>$. The probability of finding the system in the excited state is given by

$P_e(t)=\frac{\Omega^2}{\Delta^2+\Omega^2}\sin^2(\frac{t}{2}\sqrt{\Omega^2+\Delta^2})$

and the graph in the figure shows the oscillations on resonance with the two level system and off-resonance with detuning of $\Delta=0.5\Omega$. $\Omega t$ is the pulse area and $P_e(t)$ is the probability that the population of the system is in the excited state. [image]

Say I have a rectangular pulse with pulse area $\Omega t=\pi/2$ and pulse length $t=200$ns centred at $99$MHz. Then the pulse will cover the frequencies $96.5$MHz to $101.5$MHz. Is it true to say that $\Omega=\pi/400$, by the equation $\frac{\textrm{pulse area}}{\textrm{pulse length}}$ and what units would this be in? If I have a two-level system that has resonant frequency of $99$MHz, then addressing it with this pulse will put me at 0.5 on the $y$ axis for $\Omega t=\frac{\pi}{2}$ on the $x$ axis. I'm not sure how an off-resonant two-level system with frequency say $96$MHz would behave if acted on by this pulse. My model allows only for $\Delta$ to be in terms of $\Omega$, as $\Omega t$ is defined but $\Omega$ is not. How can I transform a frequency offset of $3$MHz into a value of $\Delta$ that is in terms of $\Omega$?

Comment: $\pi/400$ is a dimensionless number, not a frequency, so it can't possibly be equal to  $\Omega$.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I could calculate $\Omega$ from this graph?

Comment: You (provably) can't. The only antidote to being sloppy with your units is not being sloppy with your units.